# Self-referential $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-proof?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to show that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous then $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous. Here goes:

Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous there is $\delta > 0$ s.t. $|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x) -f(x_0)| < {\varepsilon \over \delta}$. let $x \in B(x_0, \delta)$. Then 
$$ |F(x) - F(x_0) | = |\int_a^x f(t) dt - \int_a^{x_0} f(t) dt| \stackrel{wlog \ x \ge x_0}{=} |\int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt| < \delta \cdot {\varepsilon \over \delta} = \varepsilon$$

Is this proof with "$\delta$ so that $|f(x) -f(x_0)| < {\varepsilon \over \delta}$ valid? Can it depend on the delta? What about the rest of the proof? Thanks for help.

Could I fix the argument (in the comment)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with putting a $\delta$ in the denominator, since without loss of generality we may assume that $\delta\lt 1$.  With this understanding,  the assertion that something is $\lt \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$ is *weaker* than the assertion it is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: There is definitely a problem with the final integral estimate, though.

Comment: André, thank you. I tried to fix the argument. Can you tell me if this works?
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in [a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ it attains its maximum $M = \max_{x \in [a,b]} |f(x)|$ and there is $\delta_f$ such that for $x \in B(x_0, \delta_f)$ it holds that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Then

$$ \begin{align} \left | F(x) - F(x_0) \right | &= \left | \int_a^x f(t) dt  - \int_a^{x_0} f(t) dt\right |  \stackrel{wlog x \ge x_0}{=} \left | \int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt\right | \\ 
&\le \int_{x_0}^x |f(t)|dt \le \int_{x_0}^x |f(t) - f(x_0)|dt +  \int_{x_0}^x |f(x_0)|dt \\
&< \delta_f( \varepsilon + M )
\end{align}$$

Let $\delta = \min ( \delta_f , \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon + M}) $. Then for $x \in B(x_0, \delta)$ it holds that  $|F(x)-F(x_0)| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your proof attempt.

First of all, indeed the dependence on $\delta$ is invalid. Continuity amounts to: For *given* $\epsilon$, one can find a $\delta$. But you changed the $\epsilon$ in the middle of the process...

(As André Nicolas rightly points out, for suitable $\delta$ we may ensure $\epsilon < \frac\epsilon\delta$. In general it is however a bad idea to have a dependence on $\delta$ in your $\epsilon$.)

Furthermore, your final integral estimate is not quite correct. A more suitable attempt would be:

$$\left| \int_{x_0}^x f(t) \,\mathrm dt\right| \le \int_{x_0}^x |f(t)|\,\mathrm dt \le (x-x_0)\sup_{y \in [x_0,x]} |f(y)|$$

I will leave it to you to bound this last quantity; one last hint is that given an $\epsilon_F$ for $F$, we will need to apply continuity of $f$ to a different, suitably chosen $\epsilon_f$.